# Getting error in latex while creating report

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing a report in latex but getting the following error. Following is my code......

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\lhead{}

% Title Page
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

But I am getting the following error

[image]

If anyone know the answer, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the interaction of the `devanagari` and `hyperref` packages. Leave one of them out and it works.
You need to update `devangari` to at least version 2.15. That should fix it.

BTW, you've included several packages two times in the code above. And you're using both `graphics` and `graphicx`; you should choose one. Probably `graphicx`, since you also want to use `epsfig`.

In general, questions like these are better suited for [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).